# Pygame - How does one space out randomly generated platforms evenly?

Tags: python, pygame

So, in my previous question, I received an answer that helped orient the platforms the way I wanted. However, there's a new issue that I cannot get around. How do make the platforms appear with sufficient space between them? 
(press 1 to start the game)

```
# For the program, it was necessary to import the following.
import pygame, sys, random
import pygame.locals as GAME_GLOBALS
import pygame.event as GAME_EVENTS
import pygame.time as GAME_TIME

pygame.init() # To initialise the program, we need this command. Else nothing will get started.

StartImage = pygame.image.load("Assets/Start-Screen.png")
GameOverImage = pygame.image.load("Assets/Game-Over-Screen.png")

# Window details are here
windowWidth = 1000
windowHeight = 400

surface = pygame.display.set_mode((windowWidth, windowHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption('GAME NAME HERE')

oneDown = False

gameStarted = False
gameEnded = False

gamePlatforms = []
platformSpeed = 2
platformDelay = 2000
lastPlatform = 0


gameBeganAt = 0
timer = 0

player = {
    "x": 10,
    "y": 200,
    "height": 25,
    "width": 10,
    "vy": 5
}


def drawingPlayer():
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, (248, 255, 6), (player["x"], player["y"], player["width"], player["height"]))


def movingPlayer():
    pressedKey = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if pressedKey[pygame.K_UP]:
        player["y"] -= 5
    elif pressedKey[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        player["y"] += 5


def creatingPlatform():
    global lastPlatform, platformDelay
    platformX = windowWidth
    gapPosition = random.randint(0, windowWidth)
    verticalPosition = random.randint(0, windowHeight)
    gamePlatforms.append({"pos": [platformX, verticalPosition], "gap": gapPosition}) # creating platforms
    lastPlatform = GAME_TIME.get_ticks()
    if platformDelay > 800:
        platformDelay -= 50

def movingPlatform():
    for idx, platform in enumerate(gamePlatforms):
        platform["pos"][0] -= platformSpeed
        if platform["pos"][0] < -10:
            gamePlatforms.pop(idx)

def drawingPlatform():
    global platform
    for platform in gamePlatforms:
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, (214, 200, 253), (platform["pos"][0], platform["pos"][1], 20, 80))


def gameOver():
    global gameStarted, gameEnded, platformSpeed

    platformSpeed = 0
    gameStarted = False
    gameEnded = True


def quitGame():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()


def gameStart():
    global gameStarted
    gameStarted = True


while True:
    surface.fill((95, 199, 250))
    pressedKey = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for event in GAME_EVENTS.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            # Event key for space should initiate sound toggle
            if event.key == pygame.K_1:
                oneDown = True
                gameStart()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_1:
                oneDown = False
                #KEYUP for the space bar
        if event.type == GAME_GLOBALS.QUIT:
            quitGame()

    if gameStarted is True:
        drawingPlayer()
        movingPlayer()
        creatingPlatform()
        movingPlatform()
        drawingPlatform()

    elif gameEnded is True:
        surface.blit(GameOverImage, (0, 0))

    else:
        surface.blit(StartImage, (0, 0))



    pygame.display.update()
```

I have tried increasing the value of the `platformDelay` variable, with no avail. I have also tried tinkering around with `creatingPlatform()`. No matter what I do, they always appear in clumps! I would like it to be a game where the platforms come towards the player in regular intervals so it's actually playable, but then the speed of the platforms approaching will increase over time to increase the difficulty of the game. How would I go about doing this? Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use [`pygame.time.get_ticks()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) to get the number of milliseconds the program is running. Note, since the time is given in milliseconds, a value of 1000 would be 1 second.

Initialize a variable newPlatformTimePoint by 0 and define an interval between an interval in which new platforms appear

```py
newPlatformTimePoint = 0
newPlatformInterval = 200 # 0.2 seconds
```

When the game was startedGet the current time point in the main loop and set the time point for the first platform when the game was started:

```py
timePoint = pygame.time.get_ticks()
```

```py
if event.key == pygame.K_1:
    oneDown = True
    gameStart()
    newPlatformTimePoint = timePoint + 1000 # 1 second after start
```

Add a new platform when the time point exceeded and increment set the next time point, by incrementing it by `newPlatformInterval`. Not the interval can be changed (speeded up) during the game.

```py
if gameStarted is True: 
    drawingPlayer()
    movingPlayer()
    if timePoint > newPlatformTimePoint:
        newPlatformTimePoint = timePoint + newPlatformInterval
        creatingPlatform()
    movingPlatform()
    drawingPlatform()
```

Main loop code, with the applied suggestions:

[image]

```py
newPlatformTimePoint = 0
newPlatformInterval = 200 # 0.2 seconds
while True:
    timePoint = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    surface.fill((95, 199, 250))
    pressedKey = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for event in GAME_EVENTS.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            # Event key for space should initiate sound toggle
            if event.key == pygame.K_1:
                oneDown = True
                gameStart()
                newPlatformTimePoint = timePoint + 1000 # 1 second after start

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_1:
                oneDown = False
                #KEYUP for the space bar
        if event.type == GAME_GLOBALS.QUIT:
            quitGame()

    if gameStarted is True: 
        drawingPlayer()
        movingPlayer()
        if timePoint > newPlatformTimePoint:
            newPlatformTimePoint = timePoint + newPlatformInterval
            creatingPlatform()
        movingPlatform()
        drawingPlatform()

    elif gameEnded is True:
        surface.blit(GameOverImage, (0, 0))

    else:
        surface.blit(StartImage, (0, 0))

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for this! However, it hasn't quite managed to fix my issue. I had triple checked to make sure I've added what you did, yet it still comes out as https://gyazo.com/bfd2984bcc791c44e69833eda6bab0e3

Comment: Hello, the issue is solved. I was going to respond but I wasn't sure whether it was against the rules to just say that it was with a thank you. So, I'll say thank you! I just adjusted the new platform interval to my liking :)